# How to add a random value to many rows in a Pandas Dataframe iteratively?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, random

Suppose I have a Pandas Dataframe named `df`, which has the following structure:-

```
          Column 1 Column 2 ......... Column 104
Row 1      0.01     0.55                 3
Row 2      0.03     0.14                 1
...                       
Row 100    0.75    0.56                  0
```

What I am trying to accomplish is that for all rows which match the condition given below, I need to generate `100` more rows with a random value between `0` and `0.05` added to each row:-

```
is_less = df.iloc[:,-1] > 1
df_try = df[is_less]
df = df.append([df_try]*100,ignore_index=True)
```

The problem is that I can simply duplicate the rows in `df_try` to generate `100` more rows for each case, but I want to add a random value to each row as well, such that each row is different from the others but very similar.

```
import random
df = df.append([df_try + random.uniform(0,0.05)]*100, ignore_index=True)
```

What this does is to simply add the fixed random value to `df_try`'s `100` new rows, but not a unique random value to each row. I know that this is because the above syntax does not iterate over df_try, resulting in the fixed random value being added, but is there a suitable way to add the random values iteratively over the data frame in this case?

Comment: Do you want one unique random value per row, per column (so one per element) or one per row (so the same value will be added to each column in the row)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is create 2d array with same size like new appended `DataFrame` and add to joined lists with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
N = 10
arr = np.random.uniform(0,0.05, size=(N, len(df.columns)))
is_less = df.iloc[:,-1] > 1
df_try = df[is_less]
df = df.append(pd.concat([df_try]*N) + arr,ignore_index=True)
print (df)
    Column 1  Column 2  Column 104
0   0.010000  0.550000    3.000000
1   0.030000  0.140000    1.000000
2   0.750000  0.560000    0.000000
3   0.024738  0.561647    3.045146
4   0.035315  0.584161    3.008656
5   0.022386  0.563025    3.033091
6   0.039175  0.588785    3.004649
7   0.049465  0.594903    3.003303
8   0.027366  0.580478    3.041745
9   0.044721  0.599853    3.001736
10  0.052849  0.589775    3.042434
11  0.033957  0.582610    3.045215
12  0.044349  0.582218    3.027665
```

Your solution should be changed by list comprehension if need add scalar to each `df_try`:

```
N = 10

is_less = df.iloc[:,-1] > 1
df_try = df[is_less]
df = df.append( [df_try + random.uniform(0, 0.05) for _ in range(N)], ignore_index=True)
print (df)
    Column 1  Column 2  Column 104
0   0.010000  0.550000    3.000000
1   0.030000  0.140000    1.000000
2   0.750000  0.560000    0.000000
3   0.036756  0.576756    3.026756
4   0.039357  0.579357    3.029357
5   0.048746  0.588746    3.038746
6   0.040197  0.580197    3.030197
7   0.011045  0.551045    3.001045
8   0.013942  0.553942    3.003942
9   0.054658  0.594658    3.044658
10  0.025909  0.565909    3.015909
11  0.012093  0.552093    3.002093
12  0.058463  0.598463    3.048463
```

Comment: I think you can just write `[df_try + random.uniform(0, 0.05) for _ in range(N)]`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Can this be modified so that the random values are only added to Columns 1-103 and not Column 104? I guess using df_try.iloc[:,:-1] should work or is there a more suitable way? @GZ0

Comment: @JChat - For last solution use `df = df.append( [df_try + np.append(np.repeat(random.uniform(0, 0.05), len(df.columns) - 1), [0]) for _ in range(N)], ignore_index=True)` - repeat values and add 0 for add `0` to last column

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the copies first and create a single array containing all the random values, add them together, and then append the result to the original:

```
import numpy as np

n_copies = 2

df = pd.DataFrame(np.c_[np.arange(6), np.random.randint(1, 3, size=6)])
subset = df[df.iloc[:, -1] > 1]
extra = pd.concat([subset] * n_copies).add(np.random.uniform(0, 0.05, len(subset) * n_copies), axis='rows')

result = df.append(extra, ignore_index=True)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
           0         1
0   0.000000  2.000000
1   1.000000  2.000000
2   2.000000  1.000000
3   3.000000  2.000000
4   4.000000  1.000000
5   5.000000  2.000000
6   0.007723  2.007723
7   1.005718  2.005718
8   3.003063  2.003063
9   5.005238  2.005238
10  0.006509  2.006509
11  1.034742  2.034742
12  3.022345  2.022345
13  5.040911  2.040911
```